# Load data from database to richtextbox in c# windows form using Linq

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, richtextbox

[image]

I'm trying to load Data from database to RichTextBox  (as image shows) in my c# windows form Project using Linq.

I don't know if I am doing it right, because the data is not loading to the RichTextBox. Please help.

This is how I'am trying to do it:

```
 string idNr = txtIdcardNr.Text.Trim();

 var CheckIfIdCardExist = (from u in db.Customer
                           where u.IdentityCardNr == idNr
                           select u).FirstOrDefault();
     if(CheckIfIdCardExist != null)
     {
       String template =
       @"Date\t\t{0}
       Notes\t\t{1}
       Staff\t\t{2}
       *********\t\t{3}";
              var notes = (from u in db.CustomerNotes
                           join em in db.Employee on u.StaffId equals em.EmployeeId
                           where u.CustomerId == CheckIfIdCardExist.CustomerId
                           select new {
                                         Date = u.NoteDate,
                                         notes = u.Notes,
                                         employee = em.FirstName + " " + em.LastName


                                     }).ToList();
                    foreach(var n in notes)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text = string.Format(template, n.Date, n.notes, n.employee);
                    }
```

Comment: You didn't say what this was doing that you didn't like.  However, I'm proposing a stab at it in the answers.

Comment: `richTextBox1.Text =` obviously this line is going bring you unstuck regardless of any other problem, you'll just be adding the last note

Comment: Is the image what you WANT to see?

Comment: @Ann L. thank you for response, Yes I want to see like tha tImage

Comment: Is the problem the one that @TheGeneral pointed out -- that you're only seeing your final note?  If so, I proposed a solution, below.

Comment: Are there other problems?  We can't see what you're seeing on your screen, just what you tell us or post pictures of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking a big leap here, and guessing that the primary problem is that you're not seeing all your notes, just the final one.

```
     var notes = (from u in db.CustomerNotes
                       join em in db.Employee on u.StaffId equals em.EmployeeId
                       where u.CustomerId == CheckIfIdCardExist.CustomerId
                       select new {
                                     Date = u.NoteDate,
                                     notes = u.Notes,
                                     employee = em.FirstName + " " + em.LastName


                                 });

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     foreach(var n in notes)
     {
        sb.AppendFormat(template, n.Date, n.notes, n.employee);
        sb.Append("\n");
     }
     richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: L Thank you very much. Now it's working as I want. I have deleted my \t\t and Notes , staff and **** Begins in new line as I want but but in position zero. I mean for example Notes Begins exactly after the end of Date, not longside to the left but under the end of date. I tried \n in template but did not work. But its wonderful, it's working... Thank you very much. I don't if you can see what is the problem that Notes, Staff and **** not Begins from the very left side.

Comment: It sounds as if you need a carriage return character. I don't know what that is in RTF, unfortunately.